# PHP string replace?

Tags: php, string

How can I take a string like:

```
navMenu[]=1&navMenu[]=6&navMenu[]=2&navMenu[]=3&navMenu[]=4&navMenu[]=5
```

And in php make it so that I can remove a certain value for the navMenu[], but it would still stay in the same order but with the value removed. Or add a value as well.

I have been tampering with exploding it at the & sign but am not sure how I can add or remove a value, and making sure the & sign is not at the start or end of the string.

Comment: Do you mean to remove a value, or add a value, then reformat the string like above? (Ex: Remove the `6` entry to read `navMenu[]=1&navMenu[]=2&navMenu[]=3&navMenu[]=4&navMenu[]=5`?)

Comment: Are you sure you need to do that? Can't you just get the navMenu variable from `$_GET['navMenu']`?

Comment: please revise grammar and punctuation.

Comment: @Ariel yes, this value gets saved into the database to save the users' layout, if one of the values is empty then it shouldn't be there but as it is in the DOM then when I serialize the form it still shows but as an empty navMenu[]

Comment: @Nightfirecat No, remove the 6 or any number(s) but keep the original order they are in.

Comment: @nova Maybe you should save it in a more neutral form in the database, query strings are not the most flexible format to save it in.

Comment: @novactown: I'm not sure what you mean, then, if that's not what I've done in my comment.

Comment: @deceze I have had no problems upto now saving it in this format, to get the values I just use parse_str and then use a switch statement it works fine

Comment: @Nightfirecat yes you are right didn't relialise what you had said :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'navMenu[]=1&navMenu[]=6&navMenu[]=2&navMenu[]=3&navMenu[]=4&navMenu[]=5';
parse_str($str, $values);
$values['navMenu'] = array_diff($values['navMenu'], array('3'));
echo http_build_query($values);
```

If you're getting this from the request, you don't even need `parse_str`, you can just get the already parsed string from `$_GET` or `$_POST`, remove the value, then use `http_build_query` to reassemble it into a query string.